# Program to generate the tree from its Adjacency List representation

Tags: java, json, tree

I have a JSON String which has adjacency representation of a Tree . I need to write a Program to visualize this tree . 
What will be the possible aproach ?
I need something like generated from Weka..

The sample Json is :

```
[{
          "parent_index" : -1,
          "ClassLable" : "TEMPERATURE",
          "ChildNum" : 4,
          "AttributeTest" : "NULL"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 0,
          "ClassLable" : "yes",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "<65"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 0,
          "ClassLable" : "WINDY",
          "ChildNum" : 2,
          "AttributeTest" : "65-80.5"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 2,
          "ClassLable" : "yes",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "false"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 2,
          "ClassLable" : "HUMIDITY",
          "ChildNum" : 4,
          "AttributeTest" : "true"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 4,
          "ClassLable" : "yes",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "<64"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 4,
          "ClassLable" : "no",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "64-74.5"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 4,
          "ClassLable" : "yes",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "74.5-85"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 4,
          "ClassLable" : "yes",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : ">85"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 0,
          "ClassLable" : "HUMIDITY",
          "ChildNum" : 4,
          "AttributeTest" : "80.5-96"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 9,
          "ClassLable" : "no",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "<64"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 9,
          "ClassLable" : "WINDY",
          "ChildNum" : 2,
          "AttributeTest" : "64-74.5"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 11,
          "ClassLable" : "no",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "false"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 11,
          "ClassLable" : "no",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "true"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 9,
          "ClassLable" : "WINDY",
          "ChildNum" : 2,
          "AttributeTest" : "74.5-85"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 14,
          "ClassLable" : "yes",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "false"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 14,
          "ClassLable" : "no",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : "true"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 9,
          "ClassLable" : "no",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : ">85"
     }, {
          "parent_index" : 0,
          "ClassLable" : "yes",
          "ChildNum" : 0,
          "AttributeTest" : ">96"
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Google charting API to generate the tree (I used the Org chart API)